# C# Linq and filter on sub-sublist's property

Tags: c#, linq, list

I try to filter a list on property of a sub-sublist with linq, but I don't manage to make it properly.
For example, I have these classes

```
public class MyClass1
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public List<MyClass2> MyClasses2 { get; private set; }
}

public class MyClass2
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public List<MyClass3> MyClasses3 { get; private set; }
  /* EDIT */
  public virtual void RemoveClass3(MyClass3 elementToRemove) { ... }
}
public List<myClass2> myList2_1;
public List<myClass2> myList2_2;

public class MyClass3
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public Boolean Property1 { get; set; }
}
public List<myClass3> myList3_1;
public List<myClass3> myList3_2;
public List<myClass3> myList3_3;
```

and for the data :

```
myClass3 3A = new myClass3 { Id=1, Property1=true};
myClass3 3B = new myClass3 { Id=2, Property1=false};
myClass3 3C = new myClass3 { Id=3, Property1=false};
myClass3 3D = new myClass3 { Id=4, Property1=false};
myList3_1.AddRange(new []{ 3A, 3B });
myList3_2.AddRange(new []{ 3C });
myList3_3.AddRange(new []{ 3D });

myClass2 2A = new myClass2 { Id=1, MyClasses3=myList3_1};
myClass2 2B = new myClass2 { Id=2, MyClasses3=myList3_2};
myClass2 2C = new myClass2 { Id=3, MyClasses3=myList3_3};
myList2_1.AddRange(new []{ 2A, 2B });
myList2_2.AddRange(new []{ 2C });
```

and finally

```
myClass1 1A = new MyClass1 { Id=1, MyClasses2=myList2_1 };
myClass1 1B = new MyClass1 { Id=2, MyClasses2=myList2_2 };
public List<MyClass1> list;
list.AddRange(new []{ 1A, 1B });
```

We obtain list to print like this :

```
1-1-1-true 
1-1-2-false
1-2-3-false
2-3-4-false
```

Then, with this, I want to filter my list on Property1.
For example, my filtered list on Property1 on true should be like that :

```
filtered_list = 1-1-1-true
```

I hope I'm clear enough, else I can try to explain more.

And to finish, my problem : I want to apply Linq query to list to obtain filtered_list. And I tried Any, Where.... I didn't manage to obtain a list with filtered sublists.

Thanks for help me and tell how I can use Linq to filter my List and sublists

EDIT : I saw it was impossible or almost to make it by linq in 1 step.
So I think about, with the help of dtb, another solution in 3 steps :
- filter all MyClass3 lists of all MyClass2 elements
- filter MyClass2 where there is at least 1 element in MyClasses3 list
- filter MyClass1 where there is at least 1 element in MyClasses2 list

I manage to do the 3rd step, but I don't for the 2 first. Can you help me again ?

I have a method RemoveClass3 to help for the first step (I put in MyClass2 declaration)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var result = (from x in list
              from y in x.MyClasses2
              from z in y.MyClasses3
              where z.Property1
              group new { y, z } by x.Id into g1
              select new MyClass1
              {
                  Id = g1.Key,
                  MyClasses2 = (from p in g1
                                group p.z by p.y.Id into g2
                                select new MyClass2
                                {
                                    Id = g2.Key,
                                    MyClasses3 = (from r in g2
                                                  select new MyClass3
                                                  {
                                                      Id = r.Id,
                                                      Property1 = r.Property1
                                                  }).ToList()
                                }).ToList()
              }).ToList();
```

It may be more elegant to recursively remove any unwanted items from `list` instead of using LINQ.

Comment: thanks for this laser-quick answer ! I'll try it tomorrow early and tell you the result. Thanks !

Comment: So I try, but it doesn't work full : List<MyClass1> is well filtered, but MyClasses2 and MyClasses3 are not. I obtain, on my example, the 3 first lines instead of just the first. But when I look better your purpose, I believe understanding why : the Any() doesn't filter, but only looks if one element is OK. So it brings all the elements (good and bad one).

Comment: In fact, it's a little bit more complicated : I have 3 classes and I print a table with one column by class (Id and name are printed). So I don't need to print like 1-2-3-4, it was just to present it clearer. But it doesn't :)

Comment: I give up then. I have no idea what you want.

Comment: I'm affraid about loading... This filter is used many times in my application, and I thought recursivity was too heavy for this...

Comment: no no, it's okay, thanks for your help ! Just my new comment arrives just after yours. I try your new answer, and I tell you.

Comment: Sorry dtb for my late answer, I worked on others problems... I edit my first message, you can see my new vision of this problem :) Thanks a lot for your help !

Answer (score 0):

make helper extensions:

```
    public static class MyClassHelper
    {
      public static void Output(this MyClass1 item1)
      {
        Console.Write(item1.Id);
        Console.Write("-");
        foreach (var item2 in item1.MyClasses2)
        {
          Console.Write(item2.Id);
          Console.Write("-");
          foreach (var item3 in item2.MyClasses3)
          {
            Console.Write(item3.Id);
            Console.Write("-");
            Console.Write(item3.Property1);
          }
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
      }
      public static IEnumerable<MyClass1> Flatten(this IEnumerable<MyClass1> list)
      {
        foreach (var item1 in list)
        {
          foreach (var item2 in item1.MyClasses2)
          {
            foreach (var item3 in item2.MyClasses3)
            {
              yield return new MyClass1 
               { 
                 Id = item1.Id, 
                 MyClasses2 = new[] 
                 { 
                   new MyClass2 { Id = item2.Id, MyClasses3 = new[]{item3}.ToList()}
                  }.ToList() 
               };
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

output & filter

```
    //output all
    foreach (var item1 in list.Flatten())
    {
      item1.Output();
    }

    Console.WriteLine();

    //output filtered items
    var filtered_list = list
       .Flatten()
       .Where(item1 => item1.MyClasses2
          .Any(item2 => item2.MyClasses3
            .Any(item3 => item3.Property1 == true)
          )
       )
      .ToArray();

    foreach (var item1 in filtered_list)
    {
      item1.Output();
    }
```

Comment: Hi ! Sorry for the late answer. In fact, I wanted to avoid foreach... This method will be used many times, and I think linq is better for this than 3 foreach. Now, as you can see in my edit of 1st post, I want to do it in 3 steps, and I need help for the 2 first.